# how to invoke lambda (which in vpc) from amazon api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-api-gateway

**case** : my lambda which is in `vpc` going to connect `rds` to  get some data. so here i am working on serverless web application  i want to display that lambda response on webpage itself(some table data).

1. how to create amazon api-gate-way to invoke that lambda function(in vpc) to get required  data back.
2. this api gate way url i will use in ajax section.

questions:
a. how to pass data from ajax url to this lambda function (which is in vpc) from ajax call
b.how to create api gate way to invoke this lambda function to get data back (in vpc)

any suggestions  ?

thanks

Comment: API Gateway can use a lambda in a vpc. Have you tried it and run into a specific issue while doing it?

Comment: What you've described can serve as the back-end. Are you using a front-end to present the results of the API call?

Comment: backend is lambda function only and yes i want display on webpage

Answer (score 0):

directly we can attach  amazon-api gateway to lambda( which is in vpc) to get response from that lambda.